# Unbale to Run Spring Boot Jar after proguard obusfucation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, proguard

I have obfuscated a spring boot jar using `proguard`. But I am facing a problem in running jar. I am creating the jar using Maven. How to resolve below mentioned issue.

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar'. 
It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. 
Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:285)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:248)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

Plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <proguardVersion>6.0.3</proguardVersion>
        <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
        <outjar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</outjar>
        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
        <options>
        <option>-dontshrink</option>
        <option>-dontoptimize</option>
        </options>
        <proguardInclude>${project.basedir}/proguard.cfg</proguardInclude>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
        </libs>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Do you understand the error message?

Comment: Yeah I am understanding the error message I have tried multiple ways to resolve but not successful. Can you please guide how to resolve this.

Comment: I had faced lot of issues when I first time obfuscated jars, can you edit your question and put maven also, It would be more better if you provide a github project, top of all, your problem is that you are obfuscating dependencies as well, all you need to obfuscate your source code

Comment: @ShaileshChandra can you please guide how to obusfucate only source code. I can share maven editing my question.

Comment: If you want an executable jar with jars inside, the outermost jar _must_ be uncompressed.  Currently it isn’t.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify build section of your pom, you can refer below pom or my old project

```
<build>
    <finalName>pro-kabaddi</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!--groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId -->
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>proguard</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
                <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                <outjar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</outjar>

                <libs>
                    <lib>${java.bootstrap.classes}</lib>
                    <lib>${java.cryptographic.extension.classes}</lib>
                    <lib>${java.secure.socket.extension.classes}</lib>
                </libs>
                <injarNotExistsSkip>true</injarNotExistsSkip>

            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                    <version>5.3.3</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <start-class>org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher</start-class>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

your configuration mostly look right to me

however I would like to suggest few things

- Keep all proguard related configuration in separate configuration file (proguard)
- There are log of configuration, I can't see like you need to retain annotations, some specific class
- You need to retain Main Application class

Now most important thing

Please notice execution section of my my pom.xml (spring boot plugin)

```
<executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <start-class>org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher</start-class>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
```

Look at goal part which I used **repackage**,  when you use it spring boot plugin

> Repackages existing JAR and WAR archives so that they can be executed from the command line using java -jar. With layout=NONE can also be used simply to package a JAR with nested dependencies (and no main class, so not executable).

In build process flow would be like

source jar -->  Obfuscated Jar --> Spring boot compatible jar

hope this helps, feel free to ask any question or refer my sample project avaialble [here](https://github.com/KoolShailesh/dev.git)

Answer (score 0):

add -dontcompress BOOT-INF/lib/*.jar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).